# Get correct Uri from file chooser with google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api, uri

so here is my problem, i need to get a file in phone and then upload it to my parse-server. I've made a file chooser for document, download, external, media folder but android file chooser also propose GoogleDrive option. So i got te Uri but i can't find a way to access that "local copy?".

Do i need to use GoogleDrive SDK to access it? Or can't android just be smart enough and give me methods to handle that Uri ?

I did success getting file name.

```
content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/
```

Here is my file chooser and handler:

```
public static void pick(final Controller controller) {
        final Intent chooseFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        chooseFileIntent.setType("application/pdf");
        chooseFileIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        if (chooseFileIntent.resolveActivity(controller.getContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
            controller.startActivityForResult(chooseFileIntent, Configuration.Request.Code.Pdf.Pdf);
        }
    }

    private static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static boolean isGoogleDriveUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.docs.storage".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    private static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        final String column = "_data";
        final String[] projection = { column };
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) {
        if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];

                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
            } else if (isGoogleDriveUri(uri)) {
//                Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
//                if (cursor != null) {
//                    int fileNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
//                    cursor.moveToFirst();
//                    Log.d("=== TAG ===", cursor.getString(fileNameIndex));
//                    Log.d("=== TAG ===", uri.getPath());
//                    cursor.close();
//                }
            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                final String[] split = docId.split(":");
                final String type = split[0];
                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }
                final String selection = "_id=?";
                final String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {split[1]};
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        }
        else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        }
        else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void upload(final Context context, final String name, final ParseObject dataSource, final String field, final Uri uri, final Handler handler) {
        if (context != null && name != null && dataSource != null && field != null && uri != null) {
            String path = getPath(context, uri);
            if (path != null) {
                final File file = new File(path);
                dataSource.put(field, new ParseFile(file));
                dataSource.getParseFile(field).saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            if (handler != null) {
                                handler.success();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, new ProgressCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(Integer percentDone) {
                        if (handler != null) {
                            handler.progress(percentDone);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT :**

I've made some try but i got a problem when deleting the temporary file
Here is my code:

```
public static void copyFile(final Context context, final Uri uri, final ParseObject dataSource, final String field, final String name, final Data.Source target, final Handler handler) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
                        int length;
                        while ((length = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1)  {
                            byteArrayOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, length);
                        }
                        dataSource.put(field, new ParseFile(name, byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()));
                        byteArrayOutputStream.close();
                        inputStream.close();
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
                dataSource.getParseFile(field).saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            if (handler != null) {
                                handler.success();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, new ProgressCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(Integer percentDone) {
                        if (handler != null) {
                            handler.progress(percentDone);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

Final Edit:

Here my code is correct, temporary file are created and put in cache by Parse himself, so its out of my range. Hope he can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So i got te Uri but i can't find a way to access that "local copy?".

There is no "local copy", at least one that you can access.

> Or can't android just be smart enough and give me methods to handle that Uri ?

Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. Either use that directly with your "parse-server", or use it to create a temporary "local copy" to a file that you control. Upload that local copy, deleting it when you are done.

> Here is my file chooser and handler:

`pick()` is fine. `upload()` might be fine; I have not used Parse. The rest of that code is junk, copied from prior junk. It makes many unfounded, unreliable assumptions, and it will not work for `Uri` values from arbitrary apps (e.g., served via `FileProvider`).

Comment: Do you have solution that work with most of the Uri ? Do I need to use an third tier library? I don't have time to actually dev all of this.

Thanks for answer !

Comment: @Nek: "Do you have solution that work with most of the Uri ?" -- by definition, that is not possible. A `Uri` with a `content` scheme can point to whatever that `ContentProvider` wants, and that does not have to be a file, let alone a file on the filesystem that you can access. Use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`. "I don't have time to actually dev all of this" -- copying data from an `InputStream` to a `FileOutputStream` is trivial, the sort of thing that one can read in a book on Java programming.

Comment: Okey so if I get it, I should do a file chooser that always use openInputStream and a local temporary copy to be the most general possible?

Comment: @Nek: If the `Uri` scheme is `content` or `android.resource`, yes. If the `Uri` scheme is `file`, then you should have direct filesystem access to the content via `getPath()` (assuming that the other app didn't screw up what `Uri` it gave you). `openInputStream()` handles `file` schemes as well, so if you wanted to treat that the same as `content` and `android.resource`, you can do so. Most of the time, you will get `content` nowadays.

Comment: Thanks a lot with all of this, I will try some things, and post it here when i got  the answer !

Comment: Hey you, i did some change, to you got clue why there file return false for canRead isFile etc etc.

Comment: @Nek: I do not know what file you are referring to. You may want to post a new Stack Overflow question with a new [mcve] and an explanation of what you are seeing.